# windows XP or windows 7 for Android Development using Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

I would be setting up Android Development tools like Eclipse and Java, but am not sure which Windows Operating System is best suited for it. Is windows 7 recommended over Windows XP. Would have loved Linux but it is not an option for current scenario. Please provide your inputs on the pros and cons of both the Operating Systems- XP and Win 7.

Comment: Truth be told, use what you like - the OS isn't a determiner of success/failure

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I use a Windows 7 computer and its just super. Also essential for using an SSD. As Windows current os, its also recommended for all but legacy app support (which could use a virtual os anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's depend on yourself, but I prefer Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Android development with eclipse it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real difference since everything is running over a java virtual machine. The only thing i can tell you is that the emulator will be always faster on windows XP because the OS is less resource intensive. If you plan to test programs on a real device, then there's virtually no difference.
If you want to develop in Linux i will recommend you Ubuntu since it has a larger userbase and that means more community support.

Edit: A VERY IMPORTANT DIFFERENCE:  Support for device drivers is largely hit and miss, so start from there, choose your development physical android device (tablet, phone, etc), look for ADB driver support.